# Optimizing my script; taking too long; distance between many objects PostGIS

Tags: postgis, st-distance, knn

I have many many points and want to calculate the shortest distance from each point to the closest line of a table with many many lines. I think my underneath code is correct, I however never get an answer because pgadmin just keeps 'waiting for query execution to complete'. How can I optimize this underneath script?

```
SELECT 
    max(br.id), max(to_timestamp(br.time)), max(at.linknummer), 
    min(ST_Distance(st_transform(br.geom,3857), at.geometry))
FROM
    schema1.data1 AS br,
    schema2.data2 AS at 
GROUP BY
    br.id, br.time
```

Comment: No, your code is not correct.  It is a worst-case polynomial expansion with reprojection into a coordinate system which is completely inaccurate for distance. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact row counts, the `srid` of the tables, the `EXPLAIN` plan for your query, and an indication of the worst and average case distances between points and their nearest lines.

Comment: You need to use something in the WHERE clause to limit the search, such as ST_DWithin, ST_Intersects. There are lots of questions on here with a similar question -- search for K nearest neighbours (knn) or similar. What you have is a Cartesian product.

Comment: how´s your queriying going? was I able to help?

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a possible solution, although I´m sure there are plenty similar questions out there and, as suggested in the comments, you should have come up with some details about your data and software...

Also, listen to @Vince and choose a projection suitable for distance measurements for your area of interest, maybe using `geography` type even, and maybe update your geometry column (or create an additional geometry/geography column) in advance. I will not provide any reprojection in my solution and use the column identifiers as per your question; alter the commands accordingly if you want to use different geometry/geography columns.

---

First off, make sure you have your tables' geometry indexed properly, otherwise this will probably run until the end of time:

```
CREATE INDEX schema1.data1_gix ON schema1.data1 USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX schema2.data2_gix ON schema2.data2 USING GIST (geometry);
```

To update the internal table statistics for the query plan estimation to take the indexes properly into account, run:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE schema1.data1;
VACUUM ANALYZE schema2.data2;
```

Then, to actually find the nearest line to your points, you can use the `LATERAL JOIN`, executing a subquery for each consecutive row in the main query; per definition this will scan the entire table defined in the subquery once for each row in the table defined in the main query ('eternity' is just a small scale if you do this without indexes...)
To actually use the index efficiently, use the `<->` operator instead of `ST_Distance()` in the `ORDER BY` statement (the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) on `<->` does say it's index search will kick in if also used with a constant only; in this case, I guess, each row of the main query given to the `LATERAL JOIN` as it´s parameter is considered as a constant, thus it will run an index scan on the table in the subquery):

```
SELECT br.id,
       to_timestamp(br.time),
       subquery.linknummer,
       subquery.dist
FROM schema1.data1 AS br
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT at.linknummer,
           at.geometry,
           St_Distance(at.geometry, br.geom) AS dist
    FROM schema2.data2 AS at
    ORDER BY br.geom <-> at.geometry
    LIMIT 1
) AS subquery
ON true
```

I used your identifiers as per your question in numerical order; make sure the table in the subquery is the one with the lines.
This query needs around 6 seconds to execute, with 150.000 rows in the main query's table and 75.000 rows is the subquery's table on my mid tech machine.

Comment: doesn't the syntax have to be cross join lateral?

Comment: @ziggy either as above or *CROSS JOIN LATERAL* without *ON true*. *JOIN ... ON true* should be equivalent to *CROSS JOIN* for all join types AFAIK. I use to get around 10% faster execution using *JOIN...ON true* within a simple query as above compared to the *CROSS JOIN ...* ...but I can't say why.

Comment: @ziggy according to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html) (see section *cross joins*), it's equivalent to *INNER JOIN ... ON true*, which does, of course, make sense...

Comment: cool, the on true clause always threw me off. Not sure why there would be the cross join and the inner join... on true