# Snap point to point with St_Snap Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

I write a request that allows to snap a point to another.
Here is the request:

```
 SELECT
        f.gid as gid,
        ST_Snap (f.Geom, g.Geom, min, 5) as geom
 FROM
        boiten as f,
        (SELECT ST_Collect (Geom) as Geom
        FROM ft_chambre) as g
```

It works but the snapped points missed the closest position

***Update:***

For the CRS it's 2154 ,I want to snap the point to the red ones
[image]
I modified my code to this:

```
SELECT
   f.gid as gid,
   ST_Snap(f.Geom, g.Geom, st_distance(f.Geom, g.Geom)*1.2) as geom
FROM
   boiten as f,
   (SELECT ST_Collect(Geom) as Geom
   FROM ft_chambre) as g
```

[image]
But like you see there are points witch snapped to the wrong place or has snapped to more than one.

***For exemple*** 
 This point has snapped to the wrong place where the other point has already snapped to
 [image]

Comment: How do the geometries look like? What are their coordinates? What's the CRS you're using for storing the data and for displaying the results?

Comment: What do you mean "snapped to the wrong place"? Can you give us an example of an expected behaviour, an what is actually happening instead?

Comment: so you want each greenish point (*f.Geom*, I guess?) to snap to the nearest red point (*g.Geom* ?) only if that one is not already occupied?

Comment: Yes and no i want to each point to snap to the nearest point even if ther is two points that are near each other they can snap to the same red one but in this case i have the green point wich snapped to the red wich is far

Comment: in this case, is there another red point closer? if not, your query works just fine. the *st_distance* you use as tolerance does alway find a point to snap to, but having a multipoint as reference geometry does make that harder to control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick hack to guarantee that you always snap to the closest point:

```
SELECT f.gid AS gid,
       ST_Snap(
           f.Geom,
           ST_ClosestPoint(g.Geom, f.Geom),
           ST_Distance(
               f.Geom,
               ST_ClosestPoint(g.Geom, f.Geom)
            ) * 1.01
        ) AS geom
FROM (
    SELECT ST_Collect(Geom) as Geom
    FROM ft_chambre
) AS g,
boiten AS f
```

Let me add: if this gives you the same (apoarently wrong) result, it's the tolerance that you need to define properly. If there are points that you don't want to be snapped due to them being too far, you need to specify what distance is too far.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! I've tried ST_ClosestPoint and this works well and I guess it's best to spare a bit of quickness for robustness

Comment: @Rania ben othmen as I said: quick hack...the query does have noticeable overhead due to *ST_ClosestPoint* in the distance calculation. if you want to improve on speed, try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268168/93656) query structure I gave to another question, using *LATERAL JOIN* to find the closest point for each input geometry. given proper indexing etc. that should boost speed a little. if I could help you here, consider an upvote or accepting my answer maybe?

Comment: Sure it's the less i can do , and sorry i'm still new at this  and thank you