# Is there any way to map match static points to roads using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, leaflet

I'm using **PostGIS** and **Leaflet** for positioning elements on map. Because of GNSS (GPS) error, points are not always on road. Is there any way to eliminate that error and position element to road? 
I don't have roads in database (for now).

Elements are points with gps coordinates and some attributes. Is there any way to map match elements?

Comment: If you load the vector roads you can use PostGIS  ST_Snap https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269112/snap-point-to-point-with-st-snap-postgis

Comment: ST_Snap snaps to the nearest vertex of the geometry, not the nearest point, and roads have to be in postgis too.

Comment: *Nearest Neighbor* search with [`ST_ClosestPoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html), [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279387/automatically-snapping-points-to-closest-part-of-line/279397#279397) is a close duplicate question.