# Calculating distance between a point and the nearest line, PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn, st-distance

I have to add a column to my points table storing the distance (metres) between each point and the nearest line. Both are in the same projected coordinate system. How can I do it? I've tried this but doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE st09_2019_01 ADD coast_dist_M float8;
INSERT INTO st09_2019_01 (coast_dist_M)
VALUES
(SELECT ST_Distance(st09_2019_01.geom, coastline_ln.shape)
FROM st09_2019_01, coastline_ln
ORDER BY ST_Distance(st09_2019_01.geom, coastline_ln.shape)
LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't `INSERT` into columns, only *append* rows to the table.

Run an `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE st09_2019_01 AS pt
  SET  coast_dist_m = (
    SELECT ST_Distance(pt.geom, ln.shape)
    FROM   coastline_ln AS ln
    ORDER BY
           pt.geom <-> ln.shape
    LIMIT  1
  )
;
```

---

**Related:**

- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)

**Further information on (spatial) *(K)NN* and the `<->` operator:**

- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Nearest Neighbor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/nearest-neighbor/287810#287810)
- [PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/postgis-st-closestpoint-join-error/352905#352905)
- [Optimizing my script; taking too long; distance between many objects PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268025/optimizing-my-script-taking-too-long-distance-between-many-objects-postgis/268168#268168)

Comment: What does <-> mean?

Comment: @BERA ha! Tell you what; if you promise by the god of cascading knowledge that you won't tell anyone, you _may_ check out the super secret links in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both tables need a id. The term "&& ST_Expand(p.geom, 10000))" sets the window size for the distance calculation (10km). You can change or remove it. This code will calculate de minimum distance between the each point in st09_2019_01 and the nearest point in a feature in coastline_ln layer.

update st09_2019_01 set coast_dist_M = tmp1.distance from (select tmp.pid, min(ST_distance(ST_closestpoint(tmp.r_geom, tmp.p_geom),tmp.p_geom)) as distance  from (select p.id pid, r.id rid, p.geom p_geom, r.geom r_geom from st09_2019_01 as p, coastline_ln as r where ST_closestpoint(r.geom,p.geom) && ST_Expand(p.geom, 10000)) as tmp group by pid ) tmp1 where tmp1.pid=st09_2019_01.id;